# Need confirmation for contact form to show in same place, not a separate page?

Tags: php, forms

For example, if they didn't enter an email address, then this opens in a **new** window, but I need it in the **same** window. Current code:

```
// Error message displays if email is missing
if (!$from){$errorMes3="ERROR: You didn't enter your email address. "; $error=1; }
```

Also, success message needs to be in same box and redirect to same page, Current code:

```
// display mail sent message
else {
echo (" <title>SendMail Notice: mail was successfully sent</title><body><br><br><br><br>
    <p style=\"font:11pt arial\" align=left>Your message has been successfully sent.
    <br><br><i>Thank you</i></p>
    </body></html>"); exit(0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with form action $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] and for the error & success messages you need to check the validations on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

I used a contact form where it was already integrated and that solved the problem. works great now!